# Remove Slashes From the phone Number

Tags: javascript, php

How we can Strip USA Phone Number by removing slashes and brackets. I search it from google but i cannot find it.I want to use regex, which will not remove plus sign in the start.

E.g. input: `+(123) 123/4-1234`
output: `+12312341234`

Comment: Hi, can you add to your question: sample input -- desired output -- the code you're having problems with.

Comment: preg_replace('/[^0-9,]/', '', +92312-007-4042) , so i don't want to remove + sign. That  is simple example.

Answer (score 1):

use this `/[^0-9+]/g` this will expect only `+` and numbers.

```js
run1.onclick = function() {
  //removes "(" and ")"
  output1.innerHTML = input1.value.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, ''); 
}
```

```html
<p>Remove () and / and - and space</p>
<input id="input1" type="text" value="+(123) 123/4-1234">
<input id="run1" type="button" value="run">
<span id="output1"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you. but i want only +12312341234.  But your code output +123 1234-1234  so i want to remove space and - sign , but not +

Comment: Select the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `[^0-9+]` it will pass only digits and char `+`

```js
let r= "+(123) 123/4-1234".replace(/[^0-9+]/g,'')

console.log(r);
```